# A class that implements Runnable is considered to be a 'runnable task' to ExecutorServices?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'm attempting to use Executors instead of synchronized methods to manage threads for me. But the `submit` method takes a `Runnable task` and not really a `Runnable target`, which is what I'm after, since I'm starting a single thread where the target class is going to be instantiated and ran, like so:

```
        thread = new Thread(this, "thread-process");
        thread.start();
```

I tried doing something equivalent with executors:

```
        this.exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        this.exec.submit(this);
```

The thread seems to be starting and running fine as far as I can tell, but I'm not really sure if these are equivalents? Is this the way I should be dealing with runnable target threads when using `Executors`?

Comment: The variable name does not matter. A Runnable is a Runnable.

Comment: submit method:

"Submits a Runnable task for execution and returns a Future representing that task. The Future's get method will return null upon successful completion."

start method:

"Runnable target"

Comment: Effectively the Runnable is just executed in a different Thread in both cases. The difference is that the ExecutorService reuses the Thread once the Runnable is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Yes, the two approaches accomplish the same end: some code executes on a background thread.
- Use the second (*Executors* framework) rather than explicit `Thread` instantiation.
- Do not get hung up on the name of the variable holding a reference to your `Runnable` object.

## Details

Yes, given a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) (an object with a [`run`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html#run()) method) such as this:

```
public class ReportRunnable implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println( "Reporting at " + Instant.now() );  // Passing: ( Runnable target , String name ).
    }

}
```

…then doing this:

```
Runnable runnable = new ReportRunnable() ;
thread = new Thread( runnable , "thread-process" );
thread.start();
```

…is effectively the same as doing this:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ;
… // You should be keeping a reference to the executor service, so that you can later shut it down gracefully.
Runnable runnable = new ReportRunnable() ;
executorService.submit( runnable ) ;
```

In both cases, you immediately launch some work executing on a background thread. So in that sense they have the same effect. But there are important differences too.

Understand that the *Executors* framework (see [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)) was invented to relieve most programmers in most scenarios from having to master the fine art of managing threads. So there is rarely a need for you to be instantiating `Thread` yourself anymore. Use the executor framework whenever possible.

One difference is that the executor service’s [`submit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) method returns a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object. In our code above, we ignore this returned object. But you may want to capture a reference to that object to later consult on the progress or completion status of the task.

Another difference is that you may choose to switch from a single thread to using a thread pool, automatically managed by the executor service. There are situations in which you might want a group of tasks to all share the same thread pool. The executor service makes this quite simple.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool​( 3 )
```

;

A big difference is that there are various kinds of executor services for you to leverage, offering various features. You can schedule a task to run after a certain amount of time elapses rather than run immediately. And you can run a task repeatedly, such as sending a status report email every hour.

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
… // You should be keeping a reference to the executor service, so that you can later shut it down gracefully.
Runnable runnable = new ReportRunnable() ;
ScheduledFuture<?> reportFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate( runnable , 0 , 2 , TimeUnit.HOURS ) ;
```

Yet another difference is managing thread termination, discussed below.

### Variable names are irrelevant

You said:

> But the submit method takes a Runnable task and not really a Runnable target

You seem to be getting hung up on the variable naming. **Variable naming is irrelevant** here. The [`Thread` constructor Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Runnable,java.lang.String)) uses `target`, as seen copy-pasted in my comment in my `run` method. Yet I chose to go with a variable named `runnable`. You might choose a name like `exportQuarterlySalesDataRunnable`, `task`, `target`, or `pinkElephant`.

## Terminating threads

Be aware that eventually you need to terminate your thread(s). During the run of your app, you may no longer need the thread or its currently executing work. Or your app may be ending its run, in which case you must shut down your threads or risk them continuing to run zombie-like after your app has stopped.

The executor service makes thread termination easy, with a couple of `shutdown…` methods. You can choose to interrupt any current work being done, or wait until any current work completes.

## Lambda syntax

For the sake of completeness, I will mention that you can use shorter syntax via lambda features added to modern Java.

---

Obligatory tip: Read, re-read, and read again the superb book [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://jcip.net) by Brian Goetz et al.